# Can I use getchar() to clear the buffer between scanf and fgets?

Tags: c

I have this function and it works well, but I was wondering if the usage of getchar is correct. Could I do something else instead? Thanks, guys.

```
void addRecord (struct record ** start, int account, char name[], char address[ ]);
{

    printf("Enter your account number:\n");
    scanf("%d", &account);

    getchar();
    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
    
    printf("Enter your residential address:\n");
    getaddress(address, sizeof address);
     
}
```

Comment: Yes, and you should. `int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar();` or throw it in a `for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar();) {}` loop. That way you save and check the return against both `'\n'` and `EOF`. Note, `c` must be `int` not `char`. You can put the logic in a `void empty_stdin() {...}` function and then just call `empty_stdin();` when needed.

Comment: I should use it instead of scanf and getchar()?

Comment: Why the loop? A single call to `getchar()` will fail to empty `stdin` if the user enters `"123 abc"`, etc.. for `account`.

Comment: Of course the best solution is simply to declare `char buf[1024]; printf("Enter your account number:\n"); if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) { fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout); return; } if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &account) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr); return; }` now you can be fully assured `account` contains a valid value and there will not be anything left in `stdin`... `:)` You should validate the return for `fgets()` as well to ensure the user doesn't generate a manual `EOF` with **Ctrl+d** (or **Ctrl+z** on windows)

Comment: I am going to do that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming names cannot be empty and are not allowed to start with spaces (or tabs), you can read the name with another `scanf` while skipping over all intervening whitespace.

```
    printf("Enter your account number:\n");
    int account;
    if(scanf("%d", &account) != 1) { /* error getting account */ }

    printf("Enter your name:\n");
    char name[80];
    if(scanf(" %79[^\n]", name) != 1) { /* error getting name */ }
```

The breakdown of the `" %79[^\n]"` format specifier being used is:

- the leading   space skips over one or more whitespace characters (spaces, tabs, newlines), which consumes the newline left behind by the first `scanf`, any empty lines, and any leading spaces on the next line;
- `79` is a [width specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) which limits `scanf` to reading at most `79` characters, leaving room for the terminating `\0` nul character in the 80-character destination buffer;
- `[^\n]` directs `scanf` to read a string up to (and not including) the `\n` newline character, which saves the name that the user entered into the `name` argument.

Comment: it says warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
     if(scanf(" %*[^\n]", sizeof(name) - 1, name) != 1) {

Comment: @JoanaF. Thanks for catching that. Edited and [fixed](https://godbolt.org/z/8hzfe6) now.

Answer (score 2):

`getchar()` will only fetch a single character from `stdin` . To clear `stdin` buffer, you have use `getchar()` until you get EOF (end of file) or a new line. So, instead of calling `getchar()` once, call it a loop like this:

```c
int c;
do {
    c = getchar();
} while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
```

<s>Note that the value of `EOF` is -1, so you must use `int` to handle it, as `char` is limited to 0 to 255 range.</s>

Thanks to David Ranieri, the value of EOF can be (and usually) out of the range supported by `char` , so you should use `int` (or `short` ) to handle EOF.

You can put this code inside a function like `clear_stdin` if you need to reuse this code several times.